# Warn me when I copy hidden content from a webpage

Tags: open-source, firefox, clipboard

When copying some content on a web page, it can happen that the clipboard contains *more* than what is visibly selected.

This is done for

- promotional reasons (e.g., an attribution line with link, appended, prepended or even injected somewhere inbetween),
- malicious reasons (see for example the proof of concept that you should never [copy-paste from website to terminal](http://thejh.net/misc/website-terminal-copy-paste)),
- spam prevention reasons (e.g., for [protecting an email address](http://www.azarask.in/blog/post/protecting-email-with-css/)),
- etc.

In the [25C3 talk "Tricks: makes you smile"](http://events.ccc.de/congress/2008/Fahrplan/events/2992.en.html) ([demo](http://www.ush.it/team/ascii/hack-tricks_253C_CCC2008/wysinwyc/what_you_see_is_not_what_you_copy.txt)), it was called *WYSINWYC* (What you see is not what you copy).

I’m looking for a **Firefox** solution (preferably an add-on), which must be **FLOSS**, that can **notify/warn** me somehow as soon as I have copied something invisible.
Because the hidden text can be injected via JavaScript, the warning should happen *after* copying (i.e., the content is in the clipboard), not after selecting.

(Some time ago, I [suggested](https://forums.informaction.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=6946) to include this in NoScript, but it’s probably not going to happen.)

Comment: Related Firefox feature request: [Websites can manipulate copy&paste buffer with javascript](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1591698)

Answer (score 7):

In firefox urlbar:

type in `about:config` and press enter.

Then try this: type in `dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled` in the bar below the url bar, and set to `false` by double clicking on the true.

This should disable clipboard manipulation.

Comment: And what does this downvote mean? The person doesn't like me, the solution doesn't work, or because it isn't a plugin (which the OP said it didn't have to be). The plugin that did just what OP wanted stated the above same thing.

Comment: Not my down vote, but maybe because it’s only a partial solution, as it *a)* doesn’t work for non-JS (i.e., CSS) implementations, and *b)* doesn’t warn/notify but completely prevents (which is not necessarily a bad thing; depends on the case). So, it’s not a matching solution, but certainly better than having nothing -- thanks for the tip!

Comment: It will probably be impossible to prevent the 'CSS' method as it's almost impossible to detect what's needed and what isn't by automated means.